# Percentile plot with ggplot2 / Bars with y and yend?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, percentile

I want to make a plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaQn4.png) given only the percentiles in my data.frame. So a row in my data.frame would be something like that:

```
Name; q0.05; q0.25; q0.45; q0.55; q0.75; q0.95
Italy;   76;    88;    95;   109;   112;   123
```

And this is what I directly want to translate into the plot.
Any help or suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A complete reproducable example (like what maybe you could have provided...):

```
dat <- data.frame(Name = factor(sample(letters[1:5],1000,replace = TRUE)),
                    val = runif(1000))

datSum <- ddply(dat,.(Name),summarise,q05 = quantile(val,0.05),
                                    q25 = quantile(val,0.25),
                                    q45 = quantile(val,0.45),
                                    q55 = quantile(val,0.55),
                                    q75 = quantile(val,0.75),
                                    q95 = quantile(val,0.95))
datSum$NameAlt <- 1:5
```

And the plot:

```
ggplot(datSum,aes(ymin = NameAlt - 0.2,ymax = NameAlt + 0.2)) + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = q05,xmax = q95),fill = "white",colour = "black") + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = q25,xmax = q75),fill = 'lightblue',colour = "black") +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = q45,xmax = q55),fill = 'blue',colour = "black") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:5,labels = datSum$Name)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Also for making such effort.